# show details of clicked row of bootstrap table

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I created a table and I'd like to recuperate the details of each row on a modal to edit it.
My xhtml page is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      template="/pages/indexTemplate.xhtml"> 

 <h:head>
     <title>SLEAM Book | Consult a Facebooker</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{resource['icons/hki2.gif']}"/>
        <style>
   .ui-datatable thead th, .ui-datatable tbody td, .ui-datatable tfoot td {
      border-style: none;
        </style>
        
    </h:head>
 <h:body>
     <ui:composition template="indexTemplate.xhtml">
   <ui:define name = "content">
          <h:form id="myForm">
              <h:outputText value="Add a Publication" styleClass="text-primary"/>
              <br/><br/>
              <h:inputText value="#{userBean.publicationContent}" styleClass="form-control"/>
              <br/>
              <p:commandButton value="Post" 
          action="#{userBean.createPublication}"
          styleClass="btn btn-primary"
          id="btn" ajax="true"/>
     <br/><br/><br/>
     <div class="table-responsive">
         <p:dataTable id="aa" var="car" value="#{userBean.lps}" tableStyleClass="table table-striped">
             <f:facet name="header">
                 List Of Publications
             </f:facet>
             
             <p:column headerText="Id">
                 <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
             </p:column>
             <p:column headerText="Title">
                 <h:outputText value="#{car.title}" />
             </p:column>
             <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
              <p:commandLink value="Edit" styleClass="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#myModal').modal('show');" update=":myForm" immediate="true">
                     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{userBean.selectedPublication}" />
                 </p:commandLink>
                 
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <h:form id="myForm">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Test Modal</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <p:outputPanel id="carDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                             **
                             <h:outputText value="#{userBean.selectedPublication.id}"/>
                             **
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                           </div>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
             </p:column>
         </p:dataTable>
     </div>   
    </h:form>
          </ui:define>
     </ui:composition>
 </h:body> 
</html>
```

After clicking a row of the table, a modal is displayed, but my problem is that I can't recuperate the id of the clicked row.
Have you please any idea about solving this issue, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't do that car each row hasn't its own reference.
You can take a look to this link https://blog.sixthpoint.com/calling-bootstrap-3-modal-from-jsf/.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your help.